# How can you get an ADO DataTable in code behind (available on pageload) back to the javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datatable, code-behind

On page load, I have my DataTable results available which I need to pass back to the javascript for processing.

What are my options?

1. Use a hidden field to pass the data back up. not sure how exactly, by maybe convert it to xml/json and then access it from javascript that way. Seems like a pain. No extra round trips for this approach.
2. Use webmethod/webservice to issue a call directly from the javascipt and then get back the DataTable, however this requires an extra round trip since I already have the DataTable available on pageload.
3. It is also possible to access objects in code behind using [ASP.NET inline expressions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112) (i.e. <% syntax) usable from the .aspx page. No extra round trips for this approach.
4. Convert DataTable to json/xml and then use ASP's ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript to make it available in there as a string returned from a function or something. Sounds hacky though.
5. Bind the DataTable/DataSet (or any object that implements the IEnumerable interface) to an ASP data control such as a DataGrid, DataList, Repeater, etc... and then just hide the control via some CSS: `#datacontrol {display: none;}`

How can I do this?

Comment: You can also use AJAX to retrieve data as needed instead of creating a datatable and passing all data to each browser instance. Let me know if you would like an example of this alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several of the above options, I've found **#3** ([ASP.NET inline expressions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112)) to be the best choice for accessing an ADO query result such as a DataTable or DataSet since it was the quickest to implement and had no additonal round trips due to the fact the inline expressions are resolved during the page construction.

I tried **#5** (bind data to data control, then hide it), but it was noticeably slower and I had problems finding a control that would expose all the features of a DataTable/DataSet. There are a handful of data controls that you can bind records to, but what I found was that much of the "nice-ities" that come with a DataSet/DataTable are lost when converting to a repeater control or such. If you use one of the more full featured ASP controls available to get more of those features back, you lose on performance since those controls are meant for read/write and to render the content for display. And it wasn't as simple as I expected to access the data as it is in the code behind.

I thought about **#4** (passing data thru ASP's ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript), but didn't feel like serializing/deserializing every object I need to expose and working though any hiccups that come with it. It just didn't seem like the right way. I suppose it would be fine for simpler objects though.

And **#1** (serialize data to a hidden field) is pretty much the same concept as the above #4 (passing data thru ASP's ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript so I didn't bother with that one either.

The other (2nd best) possibility is to do **#2** (using webmethod/webservice) as @Sundeep and @ron_tornambe have pointed out. However, this option adds an extra round trip to the page request and since the above scenario has the DataTable/DataSet ready for consumption on page load it is not optimal for me. If it wasn't for that I'd say it was equal to my first choice of #3 (ASP.NET inline expressions) since you'll get the full featured object to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just array, refer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92600/How-to-pass-ASP-NET-server-side-array-to-client-si).

If it is custom object, IMO it is better to call server method via. ajax requests and load them into javascript objects and work on data.

Comment: Hi Sundeep, it's not an array and just an ADO.net DataTable within a DataSet. Basically, I'm just trying to make some of the database records available in the javascript for use with Google Maps and JQueryUI. Seems like such a common case, I feel like I'm missing some fundamental concept with how to do this in ASP and ADO.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could do it as you have already reasoned through.  Any time I have had a need to do this I have written my data out to a javascript variable using the clientscript.registerclientscriptblock method and then used javascript in the page to access the variable and do the rest of the parsing.
[See this for example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19484/Register-Client-script-in-ASP-NET)

You would just use the string builder or whatever you chose to dim a javascript array containing your table values and pass that to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same requirement in one of my asp.net application. What I did was, I created a string variable from the DataTable on Page_Load() by using custom separators like :: ; etc for row-separator and column separator. And then set the string to a hidden field or textbox text with CSS {display: none;}

After that, you can get the value of the hidden-field or TextBox in javascript $(document).ready() block or javascript pageLoad function() if you want it to be executed on every full/partial postback.

Get the value and decode it as you had coded the DataTable into the string in code-behind, and process it as u need.

Hope it helps :)